# Is beginner knowledge of Java enough to develop for Android?

Tags: java, android

I just finished the book "Tech Yourself Java in 24 Hours, 6th Edition" I have an understanding of the language (by understanding I mean, the basics and everything covered in the book) and I have been experimenting and building little things with my knowledge. I want to learn about Android and was wondering if I need to increase my knowledge in Java before moving on to Android or can I just go straight to Android?

Comment: What are you wanting to program?  You are not going to write angry birds, but I am sure you could write a hello world app.  So my guess is you are somewhere between the 2.

Comment: The way I learn things is to jump right in and make a huge monstrosity of a program. Then realize that it totally sucks as I learn more and I begin refactoring.

Comment: Why is this question marked down? If you are honest about thinking it needs to be marked down, let the OP know why it was a bad question! dont be a coward and hide behind your computer screen, let him know how to make it better! I thought it was a worthy question!

Comment: @BillyNair Voting is anonymous, no one is required to explain their votes, up or down. And comments like yours aren't really welcome here, tone it down please.

Comment: teenCoder we can't really help, we really don't know what your grasp of Java _actually_ is. The only answer is the one already given by William, learn by doing, and there isn't any reason you couldn't cope with Android development without any beforehand knowledge of Java (Android is a cool way to learn Java).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Learn by doing: Jump straight into Android; follow the tutorials and Google all the things you do not understand.

It will be laborious work at first, but will speed up after a few days of study.

Comment: I suppose the key thing is to not worry about understanding everything right away. There will be a lot of things that you'll just have to take for granted, and learn later.

Comment: A substantial portion of effective learning is confidence; (not being dissuaded through a lack thereof).